# Процедуры в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, procedure

Всем добрый вечер, столкнулась с проблемой создания процедуры в ассемблере..
Язык тяжёлый в понимании для меня.. 
Прошу объясните мне пожалуйста, как работать с процедурами..
Например, процедура проверки сумма двух чисел больше ли третьего числа?
Нужно ли ей какие-то параметры передавать..
Буду очень признательна за помощь.

Comment: Чаще всего параметры нужны и часто нужно возвращаемое значение. В вашем случае ожидается, что процедура должна получить параметрами 3 числа, два из которых сложить, а с третьим сравнить и в каком то виде вернуть результат сравнения (в принципе можно ограничиться установленными флагами завершающей инструкцией сравнения)

Comment: Будьте добры, можно как-то наглядным примером?

Comment: загружаете в некие регистры, которые решили использовать как параметры, значения делаете вызов, в процедуре складываете/проверяете, в каком то регистре или просто в флагах оставляете результат, делаете возврат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть 2 способа передачи параметров - запихивать их в стек или запихивать их в регистры, а вывод результата обычно записывается в регистр rax/eax

вариант 1

```
proc func1

add eax, ebx
cmp eax, ecx
jg label1
jl label2

mov eax, 0
retn

label1:
mov eax, 1
retn

label2:
mov eax, -1
retn
```

вариант 2:

```
proc func2

pop ecx
pop ebx
pop eax

call func1

retn
```

С синтаксисом могу немного напутать, но смысл, надеюсь, ты понял

P.S.
вот нашел пару ссылок
http://devotes.narod.ru/Books/3/ch05_02a.htm

Comment: Ну со стеком так не делают, в момент вызова у вас на вершине стека лежит адрес возврата, который положил туда call, значит pop ecx загрузит в ecx этот адрес (или его часть, смотря какой был вызов) и адреса в стеке не останется, следовательно retn в конце прыгнет не известно куда. Если у вас паскалевский формат вызова (стек освобождает вызываемый) то вы должны сначала где то сохранить адрес возврата, потом забрать аргументы и после этого вернуть адрес возврата на место. Если же используется C-вызов, то просто достаете из стека параметры не pop, а mov со смещениями относительно текущего SP

Comment: да, действительно, мой косяк